HTMLand CSS not rendering in GitHub Streamlit
I am making an app with Python and Streamlit and deploying the Python code to GitHub. The HTML and CSS is working on my local system, but after deployment on GitHub, they are not working as expected.
if st.session_state.user_answer == st.session_state.correct_answer:
            st.session_state.feedback = '<p style="background-color: green; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><b style="color: black;">Correct!</b></p>'
        else:
            st.session_state.feedback = f'<p style="background-color: lightcoral; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><b style="color: black;">Incorrect.</b> The correct answer is <b>{st.session_state.correct_answer}</b></p>'

